# Find the HCF of..

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find the HCF of 
$16a^4 - 4a^2 + 4a -1$ and $8a^3+1$

My Attempt:

$2^{nd}$ expression $=8a^3+1$
$$(2a+1)(4a^2-2a+1)$$.

But, I could not factorize the first expresdion. Please help.

Comment: You don't need to factor the expressions. Just use [Eucid's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_greatest_common_divisor).

Comment: @lhf, Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Please see [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_greatest_common_divisor) also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $$16a^4-4a^2 +4a -1 $$ $$ = 16a^4 -(4a^2 -4a +1) $$ $$=(4a^2)^2-(2a-1)^2$$ $$=(4a^2+2a-1)(4a^2-2a+1) $$

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to factor the expressions. Just use [Eucid's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_greatest_common_divisor).

$16a^4 - 4a^2 + 4a -1 = 2a(8a^3+1)- 4a^2 + 2a -1$

$8a^3+1 = (-2a-1)(- 4a^2 + 2a -1) + 0$

Therefore, the gcd is $- 4a^2 + 2a -1$.